# Loop through all records in my SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following SQL script. As you can see I manually set the `@listingid` value to 30653.

But this script should be executed for all records in the `[listings]` table where `@listingid` is assigned the value of the `[listings].id` column.

```
DECLARE @profname nvarchar(150)
DECLARE @furl nvarchar(250)
DECLARE @city nvarchar(250)
DECLARE @listingid int

set @listingid=30653
--select the top 1 professionname
SELECT TOP 1 @profname=REPLACE(LOWER(pn.title),' ','-'),@furl=l.friendlyurl,@city=REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(l.city),'''',''),' ','-') FROM healthprof_professionnames hpn
INNER JOIN professionname pn ON pn.id=hpn.professionnameid
INNER JOIN listings l on l.id=hpn.healthprofid
WHERE l.id=@listingid ORDER BY pn.title

--check if current friendlyurl already contains profession
IF NOT CHARINDEX(@profname,@furl)>0
    SET @furl = @furl + '-' + @profname

IF NOT CHARINDEX(@city,@furl)>0
SET @furl = @furl + '-' + @city

SET @furl = @furl + '-3'

UPDATE listings set friendlyurl=@furl WHERE id=@listingid
```

Comment: This is very procedural thinking, rather than thinking in sets.  Create a select to grab all the records that you want to change, and then turn that into an update.  One query.  That's all you should normally need.

Comment: You can also translate the URL back to the record you are querying? Then you don't have to keep the Listings table in sync with profession   table (etc).

Comment: @TimLehner: Thanks, do you perhaps have an example on how to do that?

Comment: @Floran, it looks like Chad put up a decent translation. I'd start with that, too.  Also check out the vast resources out there, Itzik Ben-Gan's [Thinking in Sets](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql/Thinking-in-Sets-129772) is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cursor to loop over every row in a result set:

```
declare cur cursor for
select distinct id from listings

declare @listingid int
open cur
fetch next from cur into @listingid 

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- your code from above goes here

    fetch next from cur into @listingid 
END
```

That being said, I agree with Tim's comment above. Rewrite it to work in one set-based operation if at all possible. I *think* this will work, but I haven't tested it:

```
;WITH vars AS (
    SELECT id, profname, furl, city
    FROM (
        SELECT l.id,
            REPLACE(LOWER(pn.title),' ','-') as profname,
            l.friendlyurl as furl,
            REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(l.city),'''',''),' ','-') as city,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.id ORDER BY pn.title) as rnk
        FROM healthprof_professionnames hpn
        INNER JOIN professionname pn ON pn.id=hpn.professionnameid
        INNER JOIN listings l on l.id=hpn.healthprofid
    ) A
    WHERE A.rnk = 1
),
vars2 AS (
    SELECT id,
        CASE WHEN NOT CHARINDEX(profname, furl) > 0
            THEN furl + '-' + profname ELSE furl END as furl,
        city
    FROM vars
),
vars3 as (
    SELECT id,
        CASE WHEN NOT CHARINDEX(city, furl) > 0
            THEN furl + '-' + city ELSE furl END as furl
    FROM vars2
)
UPDATE listings SET friendlyurl = vars3.furl + '-3'
FROM listings INNER JOIN vars3 on vars3.id = listings.id
```